# Is there way to use existing content type field to custom form in drupal?

Tags: commerce

I want to use existing content type field in my own custom form.
Like In content type, we can use existing field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use [**field_attach_form**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7)

```
function hook_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['fname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('first name'),
  );
  $form['lname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('last name'),
  );
  //attaching existing content type fields
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article'; //content type
  field_attach_form('node', $node, $form, $form_state); //it will attach all the fields
  unset($form['body']); //unset other fields like this.
  //..
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: How I can attach a user field to a custom form? I will display that field using views in an existing view. Here is the [statuses.form.inc file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1gf5j51n7jbo81/statuses.form.inc?dl=0).

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [field_attach_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_form/7) function.

An example use of this in user.module is as follows.

```
field_attach_form('user', $form['#user'], $form, $form_state, $langcode);
```